# Repeater bind user control event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a web user control with a repeater and inside the repeater i have a dynamic number of radiobuttons, On page_load i am trying to call the onDataItemBound event of the repeater to find the radiobuttons and binding the oncheckedchanged event to a method in my code but cant get it to work, here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater_Select.ItemDataBound += Repeater_Select_OnItemDataBound; 
}


protected void Repeater_Select_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var customRbtn = (CustomRadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButton_Select");
        customRbtn.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_Select_OnCheckedChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you - http://forums.asp.net/t/1680429.aspx?bind+event+handler+for+dynamic+controls+in+repeater

Comment: @nsgocev using a method similar to that to bind the event is the same result. my breakpoint in side the oncheckedchange of ther radio button is never hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem, the problem was that i have another method being called before this `OnItemDataBound` which called `DataBind()` on the repeater, so I simply reversed the order and put the call for `OnItemDataBound` before the other method like so:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindRadioOnChecked();
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetFeaturePackData();
        }
    }

    private void BindRadioOnChecked()
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater_Select.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                CustomRadioButton customRbtn = (CustomRadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton_Select");
                customRbtn.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_Select_OnCheckedChanged;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it's inside `Page_Init` so fires before `Page_Load`